# How can I get all installed Bioconductor packages?

Tags: r, bioconductor

In my all R packages, I want to find out which packages are installed by `biocLite()`, how could I do that ? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by get all the packages that are already installed?

Comment: I have many R packages, some are installed by `install.packages()`, some are installed by `biocLite()`, I just want to find out all the packages installed by `biocLite()`.